# Хронометр в режиме обратного отсчета для API 19

Tags: java, android

возможно ли стандартными средствами сделать таймер  на API 19 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В соответствии с [документацией](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer), есть таймер:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
}.start();
```